# In AwesomeWM(git) is it possible to resize floating windows without rendering their contents in real time? (box resize)

Tags: window-managers, awesome-wm

Recently I tried out XFWM & I did not really have a good time, but I found its box_resize setting fantastic. Anyone has an idea how to do this in Awesome?

If I use 'Aero' corner snap a window outline already forms that is similar to what I would want to drag around in a hypothetical box-resize mode..